# Fade in one after the other

Tags: jquery

How to make li fade in one after the other? Here is the link where my lis are fading in while scrolling down at the same time, is s there a way to make them fade in one after the other? Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {

 tiles = $('.ajax_block_product').fadeTo(0,0);

 $(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 200;
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(2500,1);
    });
 });

 function inWindow(s){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var currentEls = $(s);
  var result = [];
  currentEls.each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var offset = el.offset();
    if(scrollTop <= offset.top && (el.height() + offset.top) < (scrollTop +   windowHeight + 200))
      result.push(this);
  });
  return $(result);
}

inWindow('.ajax_block_product').fadeTo(0,1);

});
</script>
```

The line which is responsible for fade in is -  if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(2500,1);
And here is the link if it will be helpfull - http://layot.prestatrend.com
Thanks for any reply, folks!

Answer (score 3):

You could set a `.delay()` on each one that is set to the duration of the fade animation multiplied by the index of the loop so each element will wait incrementally more before animating:

```
if (a < b) $(this).delay(i * 2500).fadeTo(2500,1);
```

Inside the `if` statement this might create gaps between the animations, you could setup another counter variable for this reason:

```
var count = 0;
tiles.each(function(i) {
    a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 200;
    if (a < b) {
        $(this).delay(count * 2500).fadeTo(2500,1);
        count++;
    }
});
```

If you want to get complicated then you could create a `.promise()` object of each `fadeTo()` function call that gets resolved in the `fadeTo()`s callback function. You could then use `$.when()` to run the next animation once one has finished.

Comment: If you setup a JSFiddle of your code I'll take a look at your implementation. This code stand-alone should behave as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, set the fading of the second as a callback function to the fading of the first:

```
if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(2500,1, function(){
    // fade the other element in here
});
```

Comment: But my element have one class name... What about .closest?

Answer (score 0):

That sample

```
showthem ($('.showus'),0);

function showthem(them,ind) {
    if (ind>=them.length) {return;}
    $(them[ind]).show(5000,function() {showthem(them,ind+1);})
    console.log(them[ind],ind);
    a=them;
}
```

you can play with it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4pkmt/1/

Comment: add function I shown to your js and use it as i described above.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case it does not work cause it start showing one after another but all but I need to show them only on viewport screen.

Comment: detection element in window it is another question. better to create new one.

Comment: As you could see at my question above I have such code for detection element at window...

Comment: so feed that elements to function;